# How to allow processing invalid input?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote and added custom validator for input data in order to prevent form being submitted (with invalid data). And it seems as a bonus I also got no processing of invalid data -- for example `ng-change` is not triggered despite the input is changing.

So how to allow processing of the input, and tell Angular to use validators for telling is the form is valid or not only?

Here it is a simple plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/AXNmvPUBGVNkwZazqUqW?p=preview When the validator returns always `true`, `ng-change` is triggered (see the console). Once you start real validation (in this case, non-empty input is invalid) you won't see `ng-change` fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the default behavior, but you can use [**ng-model-options**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) directive to make it work as you expect, as follows:

```
ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }"
```

Look at the forked <kbd>[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/F3PbpgU0trj4FciFUeXU?p=preview)</kbd>.

Comment: Thank u, was struggling for this.